# Select n random rows from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I've got a SQL Server table with about 50,000 rows in it. I want to select about 5,000 of those rows at random. I've thought of a complicated way, creating a temp table with a "random number" column, copying my table into that, looping through the temp table and updating each row with `RAND()`, and then selecting from that table where the random number column < 0.1. I'm looking for a simpler way to do it, in a single statement if possible.

[This article](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/generate-random-numbers.aspx) suggest using the `NEWID()` function. That looks promising, but I can't see how I could reliably select a certain percentage of rows.

Anybody ever do this before? Any ideas?

Comment: MSDN has a good article that covers a lot of these issues: [Selecting Rows Randomly from a Large Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Answer (score 462, accepted):

```
select top 10 percent * from [yourtable] order by newid()
```

In response to the "pure trash" comment concerning large tables: you could do it like this to improve performance.

```
select  * from [yourtable] where [yourPk] in 
(select top 10 percent [yourPk] from [yourtable] order by newid())
```

The cost of this will be the key scan of values plus the join cost, which on a large table with a small percentage selection should be reasonable.

Comment: It's always good to keep in mind that newid() isn't a really good pseudorandom number generator, at least not nearly as good as rand().  But if you just need some vaguely randomish samples and don't care about mathematical qualities and such, it'll be good enough.  Otherwise you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249301/simple-random-samples-from-a-mysql-database

Comment: newid - guid is disigned to be unique but not random.. incorrect approach

Comment: with large number of rows for example over 1 million `newid()` Sort Estimate I/O cost will be very high and will effect performance.

Comment: The use of rand() versus newid() also allows you to set a seed, which is useful if you want your query to be repeatable.

Comment: The comment about the cost of using NEWID() on large tables is not 'pure trash'. It's even mentioned in the official Microsoft Doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/software-testing/cc441928(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN. "The ORDER BY clause causes all of the rows in the table to be copied into the tempdb database, where they are sorted". The answer posted by RJardines expands on this.

Comment: @BransDs GUIDs as a whole are designed to be unique, but NEWID() really is a random number. It's a v4 UUID, which you can tell because the start of the third group is always a 4. In a v4 UUID, except for the start of the third group (always 4) and the start of the fourth group (always 8, 9, A, or B since this is the version variant) all other bits are entirely random numbers. v4 UUIDs are just fancy ~122 bit random numbers. That's it. The SQL Server doc says NEWID() is RFC4122 compliant, and RFC4122 makes the random nature explicitly clear: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.4

Comment: What is yourPk?

Answer (score 107):

Depending on your needs, `TABLESAMPLE` will get you nearly as random and better performance.
this is available on MS SQL server 2005 and later.

`TABLESAMPLE` will return data from random pages instead of random rows and therefore deos not even retrieve data that it will not return.

On a very large table I tested

```
select top 1 percent * from [tablename] order by newid()
```

took more than 20 minutes.

```
select * from [tablename] tablesample(1 percent)
```

took 2 minutes.

Performance will also improve on smaller samples in `TABLESAMPLE` whereas it will not with `newid()`.

Please keep in mind that this is not as random as the `newid()` method but will give you a decent sampling.

See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx).

Comment: As pointed out by Rob Boek below, tablesampling clumps results, and is therefore not a good way to get a *small* number of random results

Comment: You mind the question how this works: select top 1 percent * from [tablename] order by newid() since newid() is not a column in the [tablename]. Is sql server appending internally column newid() on each row and then make a sort ?

Comment: The tablesample was the best answer for me as I was doing a complex query on a very large table.  No question that it was remarkably fast.  I did get a variation in the number records returned as I ran this multiple times but all of them were within an acceptable margin of error.

Comment: @FrenkyB Yes, basically. SQL Server will generate a GUID for each row in the entire table, then sort the result set. It may have an optimized sorting algorithm to short circuit when it reaches the 1 percent threshold, but it still must generate a GUID for each row in the table before it can start the sort. Anything else would be a biased sample. For a very large table, this means SQL Server will resort to a temp table to do the sorting.

Answer (score 49):

newid()/order by will work, but will be very expensive for large result sets because it has to generate an id for every row, and then sort them.

TABLESAMPLE() is good from a performance standpoint, but you will get clumping of results (all rows on a page will be returned).

For a better performing true random sample, the best way is to filter out rows randomly. I found the following code sample in the SQL Server Books Online article *[Limiting Results Sets by Using TABLESAMPLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx)*:

> If you really want a random sample of
>   individual rows, modify your query to
>   filter out rows randomly, instead of
>   using TABLESAMPLE. For example, the
>   following query uses the NEWID
>   function to return approximately one
>   percent of the rows of the
>   Sales.SalesOrderDetail table:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
> WHERE 0.01 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(),SalesOrderID) & 0x7fffffff AS float)
>               / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
> ```
>
> The SalesOrderID column is included in
>   the CHECKSUM expression so that
>   NEWID() evaluates once per row to
>   achieve sampling on a per-row basis.
>   The expression CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(),
>   SalesOrderID) & 0x7fffffff AS float /
>   CAST (0x7fffffff AS int) evaluates to
>   a random float value between 0 and 1.

When run against a table with 1,000,000 rows, here are my results:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON

/* newid()
   rows returned: 10000
   logical reads: 3359
   CPU time: 3312 ms
   elapsed time = 3359 ms
*/
SELECT TOP 1 PERCENT Number
FROM Numbers
ORDER BY newid()

/* TABLESAMPLE
   rows returned: 9269 (varies)
   logical reads: 32
   CPU time: 0 ms
   elapsed time: 5 ms
*/
SELECT Number
FROM Numbers
TABLESAMPLE (1 PERCENT)

/* Filter
   rows returned: 9994 (varies)
   logical reads: 3359
   CPU time: 641 ms
   elapsed time: 627 ms
*/    
SELECT Number
FROM Numbers
WHERE 0.01 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), Number) & 0x7fffffff AS float) 
              / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

If you can get away with using TABLESAMPLE, it will give you the best performance. Otherwise use the newid()/filter method. newid()/order by should be last resort if you have a large result set.

Comment: I saw that article too and trying it on my code, it seems that `NewID()` is evaluated only once, instead of per row, which I don't like...

Answer (score 34):

[Selecting Rows Randomly from a Large Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx) on MSDN has a simple, well-articulated solution that addresses the large-scale performance concerns.

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1
  WHERE (ABS(CAST(
  (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) *
  RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 10
```

Comment: Very interesting. After reading the article, I don't really understand why `RAND()` doesn't return the same value for each row (which would defeat the `BINARY_CHECKSUM()` logic). Is it because it's being called inside another function rather than being part of the SELECT clause?

Comment: This query ran on a table with 6MM rows in less than a second.

Comment: I've ran this query on a table with 35 entries and kept having two of them in the result set very often. This might be a problem with `rand()` or a combination of the above - but I turned away from this solution for that reason. Also the number of results varied from 1 to 5 so this might also not be acceptable in some scenarios.

Comment: Doesn't RAND() return the same value for every row?

Comment: `RAND()` returns the same value for every row (which is why this solution is fast).  However, rows with binary checksums that are very close together are at high risk of generating similar checksum results, causing clumping when `RAND()` is small.  E.g., `(ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(111,null,null) * 0.1) as int))) % 100` == `SELECT (ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(113,null,null) * 0.1) as int))) % 100`.  If your data suffers from this problem, multiply `BINARY_CHECKSUM` by 9923.

Comment: I picked 9923 somewhat arbitrarily.  However, I wanted it to be prime (though coprime with 100 would probably be sufficient).  Also because as long as RAND() isn't very tiny, 9923 is large enough to spread out the clumps.

Comment: Founded little improvemnts on the paper: Using the a unique key column inside de checksum and adding NEWID() function instead multiply Random gives more randomness and better perfomance example:      `WHERE ABS(CONVERT(INT, BINARY_CHECKSUM(PK_Column, NEWID()))) % 100.0 < 10       -- Percent in INT from 0 to 100`

Answer (score 14):

This link have a interesting comparison between Orderby(NEWID()) and other methods for tables with 1, 7, and 13 millions of rows.

Often, when questions about how to select random rows are asked in discussion groups, the NEWID query is proposed; it is simple and works very well for small tables.

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT *
  FROM Table1
  ORDER BY NEWID()
```

However, the NEWID query has a big drawback when you use it for large tables. The ORDER BY clause causes all of the rows in the table to be copied into the tempdb database, where they are sorted. This causes two problems:

1. The sorting operation usually has a high cost associated with it.
   Sorting can use a lot of disk I/O and can run for a long time.
2. In the worst-case scenario, tempdb can run out of space. In the
   best-case scenario, tempdb can take up a large amount of disk space
   that never will be reclaimed without a manual shrink command.

What you need is a way to select rows randomly that will not use tempdb and will not get much slower as the table gets larger. Here is a new idea on how to do that:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
  WHERE (ABS(CAST(
  (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) *
  RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 10
```

The basic idea behind this query is that we want to generate a random number between 0 and 99 for each row in the table, and then choose all of those rows whose random number is less than the value of the specified percent. In this example, we want approximately 10 percent of the rows selected randomly; therefore, we choose all of the rows whose random number is less than 10.

Please read the full article in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

Just order the table by a random number and obtain the first 5,000 rows using `TOP`.

```
SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM [Table] ORDER BY newid();
```

**UPDATE**

Just tried it and a `newid()` call is sufficent - no need for all the casts and all the math.

Comment: The reason that 'all the casts and all the maths' is used is for better performance.

Answer (score 12):

If you (unlike the OP) need a specific number of records (which makes the CHECKSUM approach difficult) and desire a more random sample than TABLESAMPLE provides by itself, and also want better speed than CHECKSUM, you may make do with a merger of the TABLESAMPLE and NEWID() methods, like this:

```
DECLARE @sampleCount int = 50
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT TOP (@sampleCount) * 
FROM [yourtable] TABLESAMPLE(10 PERCENT)
ORDER BY NEWID()

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

In my case this is the most straightforward compromise between randomness (it's not really, I know) and speed. Vary the TABLESAMPLE percentage (or rows) as appropriate - the higher the percentage, the more random the sample, but expect a linear drop off in speed. (Note that TABLESAMPLE will not accept a variable)

Answer (score 11):

This is a combination of the initial seed idea and a checksum, which looks to me to give properly random results without the cost of NEWID():

```
SELECT TOP [number] 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(*) * RAND())
```

Comment: Note that CHECKSUM(*) is invalid if any of the cols are type 'xml'

Answer (score 6):

In MySQL you can do this:

```
SELECT `PRIMARY_KEY`, rand() FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5000;
```

Comment: This will not work. Since the select statement is atomic, it only grabs one random number and duplicates it for each row. You would have to reseed it on each row to force it to change.

Comment: Mmm... love vendor differences. Select is atomic on MySQL, but I suppose in a different way. This will work in MySQL.

Comment: ORDER  BY rand() worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Didn't quite see this variation in the answers yet. I had an additional constraint where I needed, given an initial seed, to select the same set of rows each time.

For MS SQL:

Minimum example:

```
select top 10 percent *
from table_name
order by rand(checksum(*))
```

Normalized execution time: 1.00

NewId() example:

```
select top 10 percent *
from table_name
order by newid()
```

Normalized execution time: 1.02

`NewId()` is insignificantly slower than `rand(checksum(*))`, so you may not want to use it against large record sets.

Selection with Initial Seed:

```
declare @seed int
set @seed = Year(getdate()) * month(getdate()) /* any other initial seed here */

select top 10 percent *
from table_name
order by rand(checksum(*) % @seed) /* any other math function here */
```

If you need to select the same set given a seed, this seems to work.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using special @seed against RAND() ?

Comment: absolutely, You used seed parameter  and fill it by date parameter, RAND() function do the same except using the complete time value, I want to know is any advantage to using handy created parameter like seed above RAND() or not?

Comment: Ah!. OK, this was a requirement of the project. I needed to generate a list of n-random rows in a deterministic way. Basically leadership wanted to know what "random" rows we'd be selecting a few days before the rows were selected and processed. By building a seed value based on the year/month I could guarantee any call to the query that year would return the same "random" list. I know, it was strange and there were probably better ways but it worked...

Comment: HAHA :) I see, but I think general meaning of random selected records is not the same records on different running query.

Comment: Note that CHECKSUM(*) is invalid if any of the cols are type 'xml'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Field1, ..., FieldN
FROM Table1
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is *an updated and improved form of sampling*. It is based on the same concept of some other answers that use `CHECKSUM` / `BINARY_CHECKSUM` and modulus.

Reasons to use an implementation similar to this one, as opposed to other answers:

- **It is *relatively fast over huge data sets*** and **can be efficiently used in/with derived queries**. Millions of pre-filtered rows can be sampled in seconds *with no tempdb usage* and, if aligned with the rest of the query, the overhead is often minimal.
- ***Does not suffer from `CHECKSUM(*)` / `BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)` issues with runs of data.* When using the `CHECKSUM(*)` approach, the rows can be selected in "chunks" and not "random" at all! This is because *CHECKSUM prefers speed over distribution*.**
- **Results in a *stable/repeatable* row selection** and can be trivially changed to produce different rows on subsequent query executions. Approaches that use `NEWID()`, such as `CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 100`, can never be stable/repeatable.
- **Allows for *increased sample precision*** and reduces introduced statistical errors. The sampling precision can also be tweaked. `CHECKSUM` only returns an `int` value.
- **Does not use `ORDER BY NEWID()`, as *ordering can become a significant bottleneck* with large input sets.** Avoiding the sorting also *reduces memory and tempdb usage*.
- Does not use `TABLESAMPLE` and thus works with a `WHERE` pre-filter.

Cons / limitations:

- Slightly slower execution times and using `CHECKSUM(*)`. Using hashbytes, as shown below, adds about 3/4 of a second of overhead per million lines. This is with my data, on my database instance: YMMV. *This overhead can be eliminated if using a persisted computed column of the resulting 'well distributed' `bigint` value from HASHBYTES.*
- Unlike the basic `SELECT TOP n .. ORDER BY NEWID()`, this is *not guaranteed* to return "exactly N" rows. Instead, it returns a *percentage* row rows where such a value is pre-determined. For very small sample sizes this could result in 0 rows selected. This limitation is shared with the `CHECKSUM(*)` approaches.

Here is the gist:

```
-- Allow a sampling precision [0, 100.0000].
declare @sample_percent decimal(7, 4) = 12.3456

select
    t.*
from t
where 1=1
    and t.Name = 'Mr. No Questionable Checksum Usages'
    and ( -- sample
        @sample_percent = 100
        or abs(
            -- Choose appropriate identity column(s) for hashbytes input.
            -- For demonstration it is assumed to be a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER rowguid column.
            convert(bigint, hashbytes('SHA1', convert(varbinary(32), t.rowguid)))
        ) % (1000 * 100) < (1000 * @sample_percent)
    )
```

Notes:

- While SHA1 is technically deprecated since SQL Server 2016, it is both sufficient for the task and is slightly faster than either MD5 or SHA2_256. Use a different hashing function as relevant. If the table already contains a hashed column (with a good distribution), that could potentially be used as well.
- Conversion of `bigint` is critical as it allows 2^63 bits of 'random space' to which to apply the modulus operator; this is much more than the 2^31 range from the CHECKSUM result. This reduces the modulus error at the limit, especially as the precision is increased.
- The sampling precision can be changed as long as the modulus operand and sample percent are multiplied appropriately. In this case, that is `1000 *` to account for the 4 digits of precision allowed in `@sample_percent`.
- Can multiply the `bigint` value by `RAND()` to return a different row sample each run. This effectively changes the permutation of the fixed hash values.
- If `@sample_percent` is 100 the query planner can eliminate the slower calculation code entirely. Remember 'parameter sniffing' rules. This allows the code to be left in the query regardless of enabling sampling.

---

Computing `@sample_percent`, with lower/upper limits, and adding a `TOP` "hint" in the query as *might* be useful when the sample is used in a derived table context.

```
-- Approximate max-sample and min-sample ranges.
-- The minimum sample percent should be non-zero within the precision.
declare @max_sample_size int = 3333333
declare @min_sample_percent decimal(7,4) = 0.3333
declare @sample_percent decimal(7,4) -- [0, 100.0000]
declare @sample_size int

-- Get initial count for determining sample percentages.
-- Remember to match the filter conditions with the usage site!
declare @rows int
select @rows = count(1)
    from t
    where 1=1
        and t.Name = 'Mr. No Questionable Checksum Usages'

-- Calculate sample percent and back-calculate actual sample size.
if @rows <= @max_sample_size begin
    set @sample_percent = 100
end else begin
    set @sample_percent = convert(float, 100) * @max_sample_size / @rows
    if @sample_percent < @min_sample_percent
        set @sample_percent = @min_sample_percent
end
set @sample_size = ceiling(@rows * @sample_percent / 100)

select *
from ..
join (
    -- Not a precise value: if limiting exactly at, can introduce more bias.
    -- Using 'option optimize for' avoids this while requiring dynamic SQL.
    select top (@sample_size + convert(int, @sample_percent + 5))
    from t
    where 1=1
        and t.Name = 'Mr. No Questionable Checksum Usages'
        and ( -- sample
            @sample_percent = 100
            or abs(
                convert(bigint, hashbytes('SHA1', convert(varbinary(32), t.rowguid)))
            ) % (1000 * 100) < (1000 * @sample_percent)
        )
) sampled
on ..
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears newid() can't be used in where clause, so this solution requires an inner query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) AS Rnd
    FROM MyTable
) vw
WHERE Rnd % 100 < 10        --10%
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using it in subquery and it returned me same rows in subquery

```
 SELECT  ID ,
            ( SELECT TOP 1
                        ImageURL
              FROM      SubTable 
              ORDER BY  NEWID()
            ) AS ImageURL,
            GETUTCDATE() ,
            1
    FROM    Mytable
```

then i solved with including parent table variable in where

```
SELECT  ID ,
            ( SELECT TOP 1
                        ImageURL
              FROM      SubTable 
              Where Mytable.ID>0
              ORDER BY  NEWID()
            ) AS ImageURL,
            GETUTCDATE() ,
            1
    FROM    Mytable
```

Note the where condtition

Answer (score 1):

The server-side processing language in use (eg PHP, .net, etc) isn't specified, but if it's PHP, grab the required number (or all the records) and instead of randomising in the query use PHP's shuffle function. I don't know if .net has an equivalent function but if it does then use that if you're using .net

ORDER BY RAND() can have quite a performance penalty, depending on how many records are involved.

Comment: I don't recall exactly what I was using this for at the time, but I was probably working in C#, maybe on a server, or maybe in a client application, not sure. C# doesn't have anything directly comparable to PHP's shuffle afaik, but it could be done by applying functions from the Random object within a Select operation, ordering the result, and then taking the top ten percent. But we'd have to read the whole table from disk on the DB server and transmit it over the network, only to discard 90% of that data. Processing it directly in the DB is almost certainly more efficient.

Comment: There is also a 'performance penalty' pulling back so much excessive data before a shuffle. Imagine a 10M row table, where one wants to select 10k rows. Even the 'performance penalty' of using a ORDER BY RAND (an approach I do not recommend) can largely offset over fetch + load + shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  * from table
where id in (
    select id from table
order by random()
limit ((select count(*) from table)*55/100))

// to select 55 percent of rows randomly
```

Comment: this isn't sql-server, which has neither random() nor limit

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have approximately N rows and you want approximately K random rows, you just need to pull any given row with a chance K/N. Using the RAND() function which gives you a fair distribution between 0 and 1, you could just do the following where PROB = K/N. Worked very quickly for me.

`SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE RAND() < PROB`

Answer (score 0):

In SQl Server 2017 and later you can use SAMPLETABLE phrase in your code like this :

`SELECT * FROM TableName TABLESAMPLE (100 ROWS)`
or
`SELECT * FROM TableName TABLESAMPLE (10 PERCENT)`

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT [number]
```

Comment: @user537824, did you try that on SQL Server? RANDOM isn't a function and LIMIT isn't a keyword. The SQL Server syntax for what you're doing would be `select top 10 percent from table_name order by rand()`, but that also doesn't work because rand() returns the same value on all rows.