# Is MsSQL NEWID bad like MySQL Rand()

Tags: mysql, sql-server, random, newid

according to this article: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/
using ORDER BY RAND() is a bad idea because:

> The problem is, MySQL will have to perform RAND() operation (which takes processing power) for every single row in the table before sorting it and giving you just 1 row.

Now some dude from work, recently discovered that you can use ORDER BY NEWID() when using MsSQL (which i do not know much about). Now, my question is, is it just as much a bad idea using NEWID() as it is using RAND() - if so, how should it be done then?

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table/848908#848908

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code invoked by `MySQL`'s `RAND()`:

```
double my_rnd(struct rand_struct *rand_st)
{
  rand_st->seed1=(rand_st->seed1*3+rand_st->seed2) % rand_st->max_value;
  rand_st->seed2=(rand_st->seed1+rand_st->seed2+33) % rand_st->max_value;
  return (((double) rand_st->seed1)/rand_st->max_value_dbl);
}
```

You can evaluate the processing power it takes for a couple of indirections, additions and moduli.

The real problem with `ORDER BY RAND()` is that it need to sort on the (possibly huge) array of randoms, not to calculate them.

The same problems holds for `SQL Server` of course.

In `MySQL`, you can avoid sorting for sampling random records:

- [**Selecting random rows**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/)

However, this solution won't work in `SQL Server` since it does not support session variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent article on how to select random rows, pseudo code for both MSSQL and MySQL: [Improving Order by rand and order by newid](http://www.webistrate.com/mssqlmysql-improving-order-by-rand-and-order-by-newid/)