# Random row pick inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select n random rows from SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table)

I have database and table like that:

**Persons**

```
id  Name
--  -----
1   Jim
2   John
3   Jaimy
```

I want to pick one row in the result randomly. Is there any function in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do it for you -

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, Name
FROM Persons
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

The Random purists won't like it.  It works by generating a new GUID for each row.
It might also hurt performance if you have a lot of rows in the `Persons` table.  Ideally you'd want to find a way to minimise the number of rows that you run that over first.

There is a more detailed [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table) that might answer the question fully.

Comment: NEWID() Creates a unique value of type uniqueidentifier. For eg: `SELECT *,NEWID() as yuniq FROM TableName` will show every row has unique value in the 'yuniq' field. And every execution of this query will generate different values in 'yuniq' field. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, Name
FROM Persons
ORDER BY NEWID()
```