# insert rows into table with cursor or C# code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am using C# and sql server 2008,I need  to select 10 random rows from one table and insert them to another table and I wanted to do this with cursor in sql server,but I have read a lot about  disadvantages  of  cursor.Now I want to do this via C# code.Does anybody have a better suggestion?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea from [Select n random rows from SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table)

No cursors required:

```
Insert Into Table1
  (col1, col2)
Select Top 10
  col1, col2
From
  Table2
Order By
  NewID()
```