# Random selection of rows from sql result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a query which will result 10 or 20 or any number number of rows. Below is the query.

```
select bookname from bookstore where recommend='true' and Year(pubdate)='2013'
```

This query can give me any number of rows.

But i have to show just 4 rows from the result. I can select top 4 but i would like select randomly so that every time same book name is not shown through out the year for the users when they visit.

Please help me how to get random rows from the result.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 4 bookname 
FROM   bookstore 
WHERE  recommend = 'true' AND
       Year(pubdate)='2013'
ORDER  BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Thanks. NEWID() was key here.

Comment: @JW웃 Hey using TOP with ORDER BY if we get 10 rows using where clause and then TOP 4 rows being selected but ORDER BY NEWID() is still applying on that 10 rows. so we need to make it as subquery  Check Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b955/3

Comment: @V...I... what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @JW웃 10 rows in a table, 6 rows filter out using where clause, then apply TOP 4 with ORDER BY NEWID() but still we're getting random rows including remaining 2 which filter out using TOP 4. hope it's clear.

Comment: @JW웃 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b955/10 check this.

Comment: @V...I... i get what you mean now. in your case, the op wants to get 4 random rows from the selected 6 rows. not the top 4 rows from the 6 result and reorder only on the 4 rows.

Comment: @V...I... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b955/13

Answer (score -2):

```
select 
   bookname 
from 
   bookstore 
where 
   recommend='true' and 
   Year(pubdate)='2013' 
order by 
   rand() 
limit 4
```

**Edit:** For slq-server use `newid()` instead of `rand()`

Comment: I don't think this will work, I believe rand() will be calculated once only in the query and will be the same for all rows : try this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d51df/1 )

Comment: No, false, it will be called for every row.

Comment: This http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d51df/7 suggests otherwise

Comment: Possibly it differs behavior in MySQL and MSSql 'cause it works in MySQL.

Comment: @IanKenney Once in SQL server, for every row in MySQL (But the question is marked as SQL-Server so your statement is correct)

Comment: Yes - it was a sqlserver question in this case

Comment: Well fine, gonna mark it in answer.

Comment: @ Cthulhu, NewID() was key here. RAND () didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah I was not aware of behavior difference of rand() between mysql and ms sql, sorry.

Comment: @ Cthulhu: Please.. you Don't have to say sorry. You tried to help me.