# Generate random names in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 5 random names each for male and female. I need to insert random names based on the gender. But how can we insert names in random from a set of 5 names in SQL. Is it possible?

Comment: I am sure it is possible, but can you post some sample data/desired result and any queries that you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: I have a weird question that I hope you'll answer - what are you using this for?  I can't think of anything off the top of my head that would require a randomly selected name from a fixed list.  Pokemon Trainer creation?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: I often use random names, random addresses, random date ranges, etc., for testing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table

Answer (score 10):

```
select name from table order by newid()
```

Comment: this will always give random list

Comment: and if you don't want to make a real table, you can always do  `select top 1 name from (select 'john' as name union select 'tim' as name....) as male_names order by newid()`

Comment: Exactly how would this work.... according to online searches: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx it creates a unique GUID type ID... this doesnt seem like it would work.

Comment: I tried it and its an interesting concept. But you forgot to select TOP 1. Here is what code I used to test it. It always returned all 3. CREATE TABLE #tmp1234
(
name varchar(10)
)

Insert into #tmp1234 (name) values ('Mary')
Insert into #tmp1234 (name) values ('Jack')
Insert into #tmp1234 (name) values ('Jill')

select name from #tmp1234 order by newid()

Comment: exactly, if you want to insert one row at a time, i assumed, as he asked to insert random names,

Comment: The query I posted above does run if you either take out `...` or replace it with more instances of `union select 'name' as name` and it will demonstrate how the idea @Md.ParvezAlam said works.

Comment: @logixologist try to execute the query 2 or 3 times, it will give you name in random order

Answer (score 5):

Create a table with the names, and an integer ID.  Then use RAND() with % 5 to get down to a value between 0 and 4 inclusively.  Add 1 if you want a male, and 6 if you want a female.  Like so:

```
Create table RandomNames
(id int,
 name varchar(100),
 gender char(1)
)

insert into RandomNames
(id, name,gender)
select 1,'Bill','M'
union
select 2,'John','M'
union
select 3,'Steve','M'
union
select 4,'Mike','M'
union
select 5,'Phil','M'
union
select 6,'Sarah','F'
union
select 7,'Ann','F'
union
select 8,'Marie','F'
union
select 9,'Liz','F'
union
select 10,'Stephanie','F'

declare @wantedGender char(1)

select @wantedGender = 'M'

select name 
from RandomNames
where id =  (CAST(RAND()*100 as int) % 5) + case when @wantedGender = 'M' then 1 else 6 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the 5 random names for male in one table and the 5 random names for female in another table. Select a random integer between 1 and 5 and cross reference to male or female table using an inner join.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how do I do this for about 300 Rows. They want me to use the given 5 names and insert them randomly into 300 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getRandomName](@gen varchar(10))
RETURNS @name varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

   SELECT TOP 1 @name = name FROM table WHERE gender=@gen ORDER BY newid()
END
```

Then, just pass @gen to the function like this

```
select dbo.getRandomName('male')
```

Or, update many rows like this:

```
UPDATE myNewTable 
   SET newName=dbo.getRandomName('male')
WHERE gender='male'
```

Comment: "Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'newid' within a function."

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, the best way to get "random" is to use `newid()`.  You can sort by this to get a sorted list.

If you have five names for each gender, you can use a CTE to store them.  The insert would then look like:

```
with names as (
      select 'M' as gender, 'Alexander' as name union all
      select 'M', 'Burt' union all
      select 'M', 'Christopher' union all
      select 'M', 'Daniel' union all
      select 'M', 'Eric' union all
      select 'F', 'Alexandra' union all
      select 'F', 'Bertha' union all
      select 'F', 'Christine' union all
      select 'F', 'Daniela' union all
      select 'F', 'Erica'
)
insert into table(name)
    select top 1 name
    from names
    where gender = @MyGender
    order by newid();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 name from RandomNames 
where gender = 'M' order by newid()
```

[**Sample fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef17d/7)