# Retrieve a single distinct value each time the query is ran

Tags: mysql, sql-server

1. i have a column full of resort id's say 44 rows, i am using the following query
2. `Query-> SELECT DISTINCT RESORT ID FROM Schema.table Name WHERE Condition='Value' AND  ROW NUMBER= 1`
3. the above query returns one value say='15'
4. when i run it multiple it is returning the same value =`'15'`!!!
5. i require a different value each time the query is ran
6. could any one please help me out.
7. Thanks,

Comment: What is condition value and row number? field of the table? Can you show your query?

Comment: Dublicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table

Answer (score 0):

You will get Random Resort ID by using this

```
SELECT    TOP 1 ResortID FROM TableName
-- WHERE     <Condition>
ORDER BY  NEWID() ASC
```

Comment: Thanks jusuraja
could you please tell me how to make this query work in DBvisualizer!