# Adding Numbers to get the target Numbers

Tags: sql-server

I want to generate a random number against StudentID, I am using the following SQL
[image]

**The Result i am getting is :**

[image]

Please Help.

Comment: What's wrong with the result you're getting? - What do you *really* want to achieve?

Comment: See the RNO_Code field it should be unique random number but its 1 for all rows

Comment: Take look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/849888/4519059) ;).

Comment: If STUDKEY is unique, then you're getting exactly the results you should expect to get.   Why don't you use the RAND() function?  http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/generate-random-numbers.aspx

Comment: "Unique" is an important restriction here. I doubt that's possible in a single statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate random number for each row in a TSQL Select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select)

Answer (score 0):

You're just setting that column to the column index of the partitioned row_number, which is 1. If you want a random number for each row, it would be easier to do this:

```
UPDATE TAB_EXAM_FORMS
SET RNO_CODE = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10 AS INT) + 1
```

Just change the multiplication to whatever range you want. This range is 1-10.

Comment: Dear johny, thanks for the answer but it generated duplicate, where i need a unique random.