# select top rows from huge table efficiently with where clause

Tags: performance, where-clause, newid

In a huge **sql server** table which is having **2,00,000** records, does the query like below should be fine considering performance perspective. Please provide your suggestions to improvise this query.

```
INSERT INTO @Results (Name, URL, MSA)    
select top 10 Name, URL, MSA from NearByCity where NearByCityId in
(select NearByCityId from dbo.NearByCity where MSA like '%Atlanta-Sandy Springs-Roswell, GA Metropolitan Statistical Area%'  )   
order by newid()
```

Comment: Why not just use one select instead of two and use the where condition in the second query in the first itself ( the 'like' clause )?

Comment: if both tables named 'NearbyCity' are in same schema (I am asking because in only one query you mentioned username.<tablename> and not in other) then why can't you merge the queries. 
IMO, 200K records is not a huge number for SQL server table. your query should do fine given all stats are in place.

Comment: Thanks for all  your response on this request. 
The references are for the same schema.

Used two queries because hav learnt newid() would degrade performance as the table grows & cost of key scan. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table

I cannot use where clause along with  percent query like,

select  * from [yourtable] where [yourPk] in 
(select top 10 percent [yourPk] from [yourtable] order by newid())

So I narrowed down the resultset and then applied newid().

Please advise, if I can correct it or my perspective isn't right.