# Pull 'n' records from each group randomly in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pull 'n' number of records from each group randomly from a table. I have tried using rownum() over(partition by.....) but I not able to pull out per group. distinct on id wouldn't work because I need more than one record per group.
consider the following table:

```
ST ID
MA  1
CA  2
IL  3
ME  4
MA  5
MA  6
MA  7
IL  8
ME  9
CA  10
CA  11
CA  12
ME  13
ME  14
IL  15
IL  16
IL  17
```

My o/p should look something like this:
when n=2

```
MA  1
CA  2
IL  3
ME  4
MA  5
CA  10
IL  16
ME  13
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select n random rows from SQL Server table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table)

Comment: I dont need the top 10 percent, I need random records per group.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by ordering the `Row_Number()` by `NewId()` and pulling only the top `N` per group:

```
Declare @N Int = 2

;With Cte As
(
    Select  ST, ID, Row_Number() Over (Partition By ST Order By NewId()) RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  ST, ID
From    Cte
Where   RN <= @N
Order By ID
```

Ordering by `NewId()` will randomly assign the `Row_Number()` value amongst the groups with each run.  So, you only need to take those with a `RN` value `<=` your `N` value.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If you need more than one number you can UNION ALL to combine the data. Each UNION will give you random number

```
create table ##Rand1 (ST Varchar(10),ID INT)
-----=========================
INSERT INTO ##Rand1
Values
('MA',1),('CA',2),('IL',3),('ME',4),('MA',5),('MA',6),('MA',7),('IL',8),('ME',9),('CA',10),
('CA',11),('CA',12),('ME',13),('ME',14),('IL',15),('IL',16),('IL',17)

------=========================
DECLARE @Random INT
DECLARE @Upper INT
DECLARE @Lower INT
SET @Lower = (select min(ID) FROM ##Rand1) ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = (select MAX(ID) FROM ##Rand1)---- One more than the highest random number
SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random AS ID
```