# Randomly Selecting Multiple Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with both Male & Female genders (PK (Id), PersonsName, IsMale). I wish to get a random name but for both genders. Example:

```
Select Top 1 PersonsName 
From MyTable 
Where IsMale = '1' 
Order by NewID()

Select Top 1 PersonsName 
From MyTable 
Where IsMale = '0' 
Order by NewID()
```

How can I combine those statements so I return 2 records (1 male and 1 female name) from the one SQL statement?

I have seen on here in the past that someone just separated the two statements in the same SQL query, like so:

```
Select Top 1 PersonsName 
From MyTable 
Where IsMale = '1' 
Order by NewID();

Select Top 1 PersonsName 
From MyTable 
Where IsMale = '0' 
Order by NewID()
```

Each time the code is run I wish to have two totally random names and not two records of the same gender so I can populate the dataset and bind it to a ListView control. I just need the SQL statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select n random rows from SQL Server table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [`UNION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) keyword

```
select PersonsName from (Select TOP 1 PersonsName From MyTable Where IsMale = '1' Order by NewID()) a
UNION ALL
Select PersonsName from (Select TOP 1 PersonsName From MyTable Where IsMale = '0' Order by NewID()) b
```

This will return 1 result set with 2 rows.

Comment: This fails and even if I put into SQL Management Studio it says incorrect Syntax near Union and other people say you can have only one order by statement. Another question here then says to embed the statements like: select * from (select top 1 ... order by newid()) as T Union select * from (select top 1... order by newid()) as T order by PersonsName ASC which seems to work

Comment: @MyNameHere syntax fixed, just put the orderby in a subquery, You may want to use UNION ALL instead of UNION like the other example you found. if you don't use ALL you could get 1 row returned if you randomly picked a name that is both a boys name and a girls name. If you don't have the ALL it performs a DISTINCT on the result.

Comment: Thank you Scott, that's a great tip!!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Row_Number() and the WITH TIES clause.  This will return one of each.

```
Select Top 1 with Ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By IsMale Order by NewID())
```

On a side-note.  Top 4 will give you two of each

Answer (score 0):

Use union keyword for avoiding same duplicates records.
Union is a keyword, use for writing two sql query which return same **type** of records with same number of columns(columns names can be differ but alias should me same for two queries).

`Select Top 1 PersonsName From MyTable Where IsMale = '1' Order by NewID()
union
Select Top 1 PersonsName From MyTable Where IsMale = '0' Order by NewID()`

Comment: Isn't this exactly same as Scott Chamberlain's answer, except you have union instead of union all -- and why would you try to remove the second row as a duplicate?