# SQL server getting random number of random rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

Is there a way to get random N rows from SQL server table? I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table), but that is not what I want. I want to get different number of rows each time I run the query - for example, 5 rows, 10 rows etc

Comment: `select top (cast(rand() * 10 as int)) * from table`?..

Comment: Please add this as an answer and i will accept it..thanks!

Comment: At least you need to add the ordering, otherwise you'd be getting the same rows, although different amount of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GSerg wrote the following comment:

> `select top (cast(rand() * 10 as int)) * from table`

Comment: Although there is no guarantee as to which rows are returned when using `top` without `order by`, this hardly seems to return a "random number of _random_ rows".

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t 
     ) t cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt, rand() as rnd from t) x
where seqnum < cnt * rnd;
```