# Select random records with no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random, selection

For an auditing project, need to select at random three tracking IDs per associate and cannot be dups. Wondering if it's possible with SQL?

Sample SQL Server Data:

| Associate | Tracking ID |
| --- | --- |
| Smith, Mary | TRK65152 |
| Smith, Mary | TRK74183 |
| Smith, Mary | TRK35154 |
| Smith, Mary | TRK23117 |
| Smith, Mary | TRK11889 |
| Jones, Walter | TRK17364 |
| Jones, Walter | TRK91736 |
| Jones, Walter | TRK88234 |
| Jones, Walter | TRK80012 |
| Jones, Walter | TRK55874 |
| Williams, Tony | TRK58142 |
| Williams, Tony | TRK47336 |
| Williams, Tony | TRK13254 |
| Williams, Tony | TRK28596 |
| Williams, Tony | TRK33371 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select n random rows from SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table)

Comment: Please refer this. [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER` here with a random ordering:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Associate ORDER BY NEWID()) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Associate, TrackingID
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3;
```