# Add duplicate records to sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 300,000K records in the sql table and i want to add duplicate records randomly to that table at least 100,000k duplicate records need to be added to the table.

Purpose:
I am doing bulk load testing from our end if our process checks for duplicate records.

I have no clue on how to take this forward, can anyone help me.

Comment: `INSERT INTO... SELECT TOP (100000) ... FROM...`?

Comment: looking for random not the top 100000k records.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select n random rows from SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table)

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` they are arbitrary, @user15132810 . Note I didn't include one.

Comment: @Larnu You know that "arbitrary" is not "random". If OP really wants random (which might be questionable), then TOP will not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: True, but arbitrary often fulfils the requirements; especially considering all the OP is doing is testing a process we know little/nothing about, @SMor .