# How to Select one random url from a domain - Table: ID | URL | Domain - must be fast

Tags: mysql, select, random, unique

I need a **fast** query for this table:

id|url|domain

example:

```
   ID   URL                             Domain
    1   http://www.google.de/example1   http://www.google.de
    2   http://www.google.de/example2   http://www.google.de
    3   http://www.google.de/example3   http://www.google.de
    4   http://www.yahoo.de/example1    http://www.yahoo.de
    5   http://www.yahoo.de/example1    http://www.yahoo.de
    6   http://www.yahoo.de/example1    http://www.yahoo.de
```

The table contains 1 millions rows...so a query should return a respond very fast..

for example i like to get 1000 unique random urls without having duplicate domains in it....

i tried something like:

```
SELECT x.* 
    FROM ( SELECT * 
               FROM table 
               ORDER BY RAND() ) x 
    GROUP BY domain LIMIT 1000
```

but it takes 1 minute to gave me some results...thats too time consuming

table structure is myisam, but could be converted to anything else if i got faster results

need some help

thank you

Comment: Do you need "real" randomness? If not, you can generate the random numbers in an array (or another table) separately and get chunks (e.g. via an offset).

Comment: yep, each query has to return a nearly different result set,

Comment: This might be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249301/simple-random-samples-from-a-mysql-database . I agree with their conclusion: anything other than SQL would probably be more efficient.

Comment: <code>
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM table limit 10;";
$result = mysql_query($query);


while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table where domain = '".$row['domain']."' order by rand();";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($row2);
echo "</pre>";
}

echo "done";

?>
<code>

i just get 10 random urls but takes about 50 seconds.....

Comment: the code format....i dont understand....lol

Comment: @user1082391 Don't post obfuscated code into a comment - if it's an answer, post it as an answer with all the pretty formatting that allows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  RAND() AS 'my_rand', t.*
FROM table t 
GROUP_BY domain
ORDER BY my_rand LIMIT 1000
```

I'm not sure how truly random that is, but it returns seemingly random results in my test database.

I'm not sure you can do this in a simple query without scanning all of the rows.