# Python increase performance of random.sample

Tags: python, performance, optimization, random, dictionary

I am writing a function to select randomly elements stored in a dictionary:

```
import random
from liblas import file as lasfile
from collections import defaultdict

def point_random_selection(list,k):
    try:
        sample_point = random.sample(list,k)
    except ValueError:
        sample_point = list
    return(sample_point)

def world2Pixel_Id(x,y,X_Min,Y_Max,xDist,yDist):
    col = int((x - X_Min)/xDist)
    row = int((Y_Max - y)/yDist)
    return("{0}_{1}".format(col,row))

def point_GridGroups(inFile,X_Min,Y_Max,xDist,yDist):
    Groups = defaultdict(list)
    for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'):
        id = world2Pixel_Id(p.x,p.y,X_Min,Y_Max,xDist,yDist)
        Groups[id].append(p)
    return(Groups)
```

where k is the number of element to select. Groups is the dictionary

```
file_out = lasfile.File("outPut",mode='w',header= h)
for m in Groups.iteritems():
   # select k point for each dictionary key 
   point_selected = point_random_selection(m[1],k)
   for l in xrange(len(point_selected)):
     # save the data 
     file_out.write(point_selected[l])
file_out.close()
```

My problem is that this approach is extremely slow (for file of ~800 Mb around 4 days)

Comment: `random.sample()` speed is already optimized but if you throw extremely large inputs at it, you have a different problem. What is in `Groups`? Is `Groups` filled with data points from the 800 MB file?

Comment: Dear  Martijn yes Gropus is filled with data points from the 800 MB file. Probabely the bottle neck is file_out.write(point_selected[l]) also if liblas is in C++

Comment: How much data do you generate, what are you writing *to*, etc. Did you profile your code and determine that it's `random.sample()` that is slow here or are you just guessing?

Comment: There are ways to take a random sample of lines from a file without reading the whole file into memory. See [Python random N lines from large file (no duplicate lines)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12279017) and [Python random lines from subfolders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12128948)

Comment: the problem is i need to read the point file (x,y) give an ID in function of the spatial position inside a grid (ex: 1 m x 1 m) and extract random one point (o more) for each grid. For this reason i need read before the whole point file.

Comment: The random sample on read trick can be expanded to cover multiple categories quite easily. It depends on the input data; if you don't need to process the input data based on other data in the same file, you don't need to retain anything in memory other than the sample picked so far.

Comment: Dear Martijn i had other function i wrote. With point_GridGroups i create the dictionary. About your suggestion, please do you have an easy example that i can study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and update your samples *as you read the coordinates*. This at least saves you from having to store everything in memory before running your sample. *This is not guaranteed to make things faster*.

The following is based off of [BlkKnght's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12134726) to build a random sample from file input without retaining all the lines. This just expanded it to keep multiple samples instead.

```
import random
from liblas import file as lasfile
from collections import defaultdict


def world2Pixel_Id(x, y, X_Min, Y_Max, xDist, yDist):
    col = int((x - X_Min) / xDist)
    row = int((Y_Max - y) / yDist)
    return (col, row)

def random_grouped_samples(infile, n, X_Min, Y_Max, xDist, yDist):
    """Select up to n points *per group* from infile"""

    groupcounts = defaultdict(int)
    samples = defaultdict(list)

    for p in lasfile.File(inFile, None, 'r'):
        id = world2Pixel_Id(p.x, p.y, X_Min, Y_Max, xDist, yDist)
        i = groupcounts[id]
        r = random.randint(0, i)

        if r < n:
            if i < n:
                samples[id].insert(r, p)  # add first n items in random order
            else:
                samples[id][r] = p  # at a decreasing rate, replace random items

        groupcounts[id] += 1

    return samples
```

The above function takes `inFile` and your boundary coordinates, as well as the sample size `n`, and returns grouped samples that have at most `n` items in each group, picked uniformly.

Because all you use the `id` for is as a group key, I reduced it to only calculating the `col, row` tuple, there is no need to make it a string.

You can write these out to a file with:

```
file_out = lasfile.File("outPut",mode='w',header= h)

for group in samples.itervalues():
    for p in group:
        file_out.write(p)

file_out.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, you are always great!!!. I am looking also for a strategy to pick random and replace values in a Python dictionary. I hope that can speed the system. What do you think?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean there. The above code reduces the problem to picking a random number for each read point; if things are still slow then the `liblas` reading/writing code is the bottleneck. Not sure what you could do about that.

Comment: example: running "for m in Groups.iteritems():"
 m ('3565_179', [<liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000000DB477AC8>,
  <liblas.point.Point object at 0x00000000DB484B38>])
I wish to select random an element and reaplce it inside the dictionary. In the end i have a new dictionary where for each Key there is only one point. Form this new dictionary i wish to save the file

Comment: But why did you start with a sample then? Or are you writing a *second* file with *one* random pick from each group? In that case just loop over all the groups, and write out the result of `random.choice()`. No need to replace the lists in the `dict`.

Comment: i am testing your solution: i have always this error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<editor selection>", line 22, in random_grouped_samples
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @Gianni: Ah, I think there was an off-by-one error in there; try again with the update.

Comment: it works. just correct random_grouped_samples(infile, n, X_Min, Y_Max, xDist, yDist) to random_grouped_samples(inFile, n, X_Min, Y_Max, xDist, yDist), with inFile instead of infile