# Value Error : invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new in Python and I don't know why I'm getting this error sometimes.

This is the code:

```
import random
sorteio = []
urna = open("urna.txt")

y = 1
while y <= 50:
    sort = int(random.random() * 392)
    print sort
    while sort > 0:
        x = urna.readline()
        sort = sort - 1
    print x  
    sorteio = sorteio + [int(x)]
    y = y + 1
print sorteio
```

Where urna.txt is a file on this format:

```
1156
459
277
166
638
885
482
879
33
559
```

I'll be grateful if anyone knows why this error appears and how to fix it.

Comment: is your goal to read in the text file and sort only a random part of the values?  are you aware that you are only storing the last value that you read out?

Comment: yes, but i tought that "sorteio = sorteio + [int(x)]" was storing all values in a list... how can i store then all?

Comment: Could you tell me what the point of the `while <= 50` is here?  Could you post your expected output, that would help in solving your problems

Comment: I have to randomly select 50 numbers urna.txt file (each one represents an id in a db) and stores them in a list and then retrieve the data for each id and print them

Comment: i guess i've just figure out another problem: the random search has to be all over the file every time, but the way i coded the next loop will be on a smaller part of the file, right?

Comment: so wait, what is the `sort` variable for then?

Comment: it's the "index" of the id on the file urna.txt

Comment: are you saying start on the `sort`th line and read the next 50 values after it?

Comment: thanks for the help, i just got the results i wanted

Answer (score 2):

Upon attempting to read past the end of the file, you're getting an empty string `''` which cannot be converted to an int.

```
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

to satisfy the requirement of selecting 50 random lines from the text value, if I understand your problem correctly:

```
import random

with open("urna.txt") as urna:
    sorteio = [int(line) for line in urna] # all lines of the file as ints

selection = random.sample(sorteio, 50)

print selection
```

Comment: `random.sample` would be a more direct way to get a specific number of randomly chosen items.

Comment: In general, it is much easier to use a `for` loop to loop over the lines of a file. Ryan's answer uses a list comprehension which contains a `for` loop, but you can also write it as `for line in file:` just like you would for other `for` loops. Just for reference.

Answer (score 1):

`.readline()` returns an empty string when you come to the end of the file, and that is not a valid number.

Test for it:

```
if x.strip():  # not empty apart from whitespace
    sorteio = sorteio + [int(x)]
```

You appear to beappending to a list; lists have a method for that:

```
sorteio.append(int(x))
```

If you want to get a random sample from your file, there are better methods. One is to read *all* values, then use `random.sample()`, or you can pick values as you read the file line by line all the while adjusting the likelihood the next line is part of the sample.  See [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12295896) for a more in-depth discussion on that subject.

Comment: i added this line on the code and it runs, but the results are not what i was expecting... the result i'm looking for is something like this: to read in the text file and sort only a random part of the values and add then to a list. the result i got is only the strings that are "pure numbers" (whithout whitespaces or "\n" for example)