# Python: compare two text files for same random lines

Tags: python, compare

I got a file wordlist.txt with 100 random words in it, each on a separate line. I currently use the following code to grab 12 random words from this file. To avoid picking exactly the same 12 words i want to builtin an extra check. 
The 12 random words are written to output.txt. How can i make my script compare the 12 random words (in the same order) with the 12 random words i have in output.txt (in 1 line)?

I currently use the following to read 12 random words from wordlist.txt and write them to output.txt:

```
teller = 0

while True:
    teller += 1

    #Choose 12 random words and write to textfile
    print "\nRound",teller
    f1=open('output.txt', 'w+')
    count = 0
    while (count<12):
        f1.write(random.choice([x.rstrip() for x in open('wordlist.txt')])+ " ")
        count += 1
    f1.close()
```

Comment: `random.sample` could be useful here.

Comment: can you give me an example of it? or a link with explanation?

Comment: can you mail me? somehow the i can't figure out the edit... :(  idokasse a(t) gmail

Comment: No, we cannot email you. Stack Overflow is about helping *other* people too. If they have the same or a similar question, they can read the answers posted *here*, but email to you can only be read by you.

Comment: Also, please don't try to try to give feedback to answers by editing the post. You can add comments *below* an answer. I've updated my answer to show an option to pick twelve new words that were not in `output.txt` before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `random.choice()`, read all words into a list and use [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as wlist:
    words = [w.strip() for w in wlist]
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for word in random.sample(words, 12):
        output.write(word + '\n')
```

`random.sample()` is guaranteed to pick 12 different words from your input list.

Because your wordlist is small (just 100 words), reading them all into a list in memory is more than fine.

If your input file is larger (megabytes to gigabytes), you may want to move to an algorithm that [can pick a uniform sample out of any iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279017/python-random-n-lines-from-large-file-no-duplicate-lines/12295896#12295896) regardless of size, only requiring memory for the output sample size.

If you need to find 12 random words that are not yet present in `output.txt` *from a previous run*, you need to read those into a set first:

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as wlist:
    words = [w.strip() for w in wlist]

with open('output.txt', 'r') as output:
    seen = {w.strip() for w in output}

with open('output.txt', 'a') as output:
    count = 0
    while count < 12:
        new_word = random.choice(words)
        if new_word in seen:
            words.remove(new_word)
            continue
        seen.add(new_word)
        output.write(new_word + '\n')
        count += 1
```

Here, I open the `output.txt` file with `'a'` for appending instead, to add the new 12 words we had not yet seen before.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems i'm doing something wrong with indented blocks it says, i have it right now as this: http://pastebin.com/RYFnPP9H

Comment: Yes, the indentation there is entirely wrong. Don't mix tabs and spaces in your editor, and look carefully at the code; a `with` statement creates a new block, so lines below it are indented, etc.

Comment: more like this? im sorry, i dont see whats wrong here.. http://pastebin.com/34YxP0t5  please tell me what i have wrong. i only have tabs, no spaces used. it tells me there is something wrong with line 20, but i cant figure it out? it is indented?

Comment: No, match the indentation in my answer. The three `with` statements are aligned.

Comment: stil line 20 (words = [w.strip() for w in wlist] ) wrong when i match it like you code?