# How do i prevent changing multiple lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, shuffle

I have this script that should make two different lists. but instead, it changes both of them so they're the same.

```
from random import shuffle

my_list = [1,2,3,4]
second_list = []
shuffle(my_list)
second_list.extend(my_list)

print(my_list,second_list)
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Someone has probably already asked this. but I didn't know how to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the original and the shuffled list at the output, you have to shuffle after saving the original list

```
from random import shuffle

my_list = [1,2,3,4]
second_list = []
second_list.extend(my_list)
shuffle(my_list)

print(my_list,second_list)
```

Or if you want 2 shuffled lists:

```
from random import shuffle

my_list = [1,2,3,4]
second_list = []
second_list.extend(my_list)
shuffle(my_list)
shuffle(second_list)

print(my_list,second_list)
```

Comment: yeah, that's because you were copying the list after shuffling it.

Comment: In another project im having a really large list. would there be a easier way to do this without having to shuffle every part of it?

Comment: That's on another topic, but check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862688/10116997 It initializes a RNG for a minute, but calls to it are extremely fast.