# Get 'n' Unique random lines from a text file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file with ~1000 lines, and i wanted to take unique (not repeating) random 15 lines from the text file.

I tried this.

```
from random import choice
lines = [a.strip() for a in open("FailsCollection.txt").readlines()]
result = [choice(lines) for a in range(15)]
```

but this was not selecting unique lines, sometimes the same line was repeating in the 15 lines output.

from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22842411/4886022) I tried this also

```
import random
from random import choice
lines = [a.strip() for a in open("FailsCollection.txt").readlines()]
result = [choice(lines) for a in random.sample(range(1, 1000), 15)]
```

But again the lines were not unique.

Can anyone please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python random N lines from large file (no duplicate lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279017/python-random-n-lines-from-large-file-no-duplicate-lines)

Comment: You know `sample`, so use it on the lines?

Comment: @J.M.Arnold That one seems much harder, though, and the answers there more complicated than necessary here (as they're trying to be efficient).

Comment: *"sometimes the same line was repeating in the 15 lines output"* - That's rather impossible to believe. Randomly picking the same line out of 1000 lines 15 times in a row is extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple one:

```
import random

with open("FailsCollection.txt") as f:
    result = random.sample(list(f), 15)
```

Comment: yes this worked.. Great, thanks alot. and also thanks for the comments on the other question  moderator pointed to. that question was not helping me .

Answer (score 1):

Use `random.sample`

Try this code:

```
from random import sample
n=15
indexes = random.sample(range(0,1000),n)
file = open("FailsCollection.txt").readlines()
lines = []
for i in indexes:
   lines.append(file[i].strip())
print(lines)
```

Comment: They said "~1000 lines", so there might be fewer than 1000 and your code might crash with index-out-of-range.