# Python random sample with a generator / iterable / iterator

Tags: python, random, generator

Do you know if there is a way to get python's `random.sample` to work with a generator object. I am trying to get a random sample from a very large text corpus. The problem is that `random.sample()` raises the following error.

```
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

I was thinking that maybe there is some way of doing this with something from `itertools` but couldn't find anything with a bit of searching.

A somewhat made up example:

```
import random
def list_item(ls):
    for item in ls:
        yield item

random.sample( list_item(range(100)), 20 )
```

---

---

**UPDATE**

---

As per `MartinPieters`'s request I did some timing of the currently proposed three methods. The results are as follows.

```
Sampling 1000 from 10000
Using iterSample 0.0163 s
Using sample_from_iterable 0.0098 s
Using iter_sample_fast 0.0148 s

Sampling 10000 from 100000
Using iterSample 0.1786 s
Using sample_from_iterable 0.1320 s
Using iter_sample_fast 0.1576 s

Sampling 100000 from 1000000
Using iterSample 3.2740 s
Using sample_from_iterable 1.9860 s
Using iter_sample_fast 1.4586 s

Sampling 200000 from 1000000
Using iterSample 7.6115 s
Using sample_from_iterable 3.0663 s
Using iter_sample_fast 1.4101 s

Sampling 500000 from 1000000
Using iterSample 39.2595 s
Using sample_from_iterable 4.9994 s
Using iter_sample_fast 1.2178 s

Sampling 2000000 from 5000000
Using iterSample 798.8016 s
Using sample_from_iterable 28.6618 s
Using iter_sample_fast 6.6482 s
```

So it turns out that the `array.insert` has a serious drawback when it comes to large sample sizes. The code I used to time the methods

```
from heapq import nlargest
import random
import timeit


def iterSample(iterable, samplesize):
    results = []
    for i, v in enumerate(iterable):
        r = random.randint(0, i)
        if r < samplesize:
            if i < samplesize:
                results.insert(r, v) # add first samplesize items in random order
            else:
                results[r] = v # at a decreasing rate, replace random items

    if len(results) < samplesize:
        raise ValueError("Sample larger than population.")

    return results

def sample_from_iterable(iterable, samplesize):
    return (x for _, x in nlargest(samplesize, ((random.random(), x) for x in iterable)))

def iter_sample_fast(iterable, samplesize):
    results = []
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    # Fill in the first samplesize elements:
    for _ in xrange(samplesize):
        results.append(iterator.next())
    random.shuffle(results)  # Randomize their positions
    for i, v in enumerate(iterator, samplesize):
        r = random.randint(0, i)
        if r < samplesize:
            results[r] = v  # at a decreasing rate, replace random items

    if len(results) < samplesize:
        raise ValueError("Sample larger than population.")
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pop_sizes = [int(10e+3),int(10e+4),int(10e+5),int(10e+5),int(10e+5),int(10e+5)*5]
    k_sizes = [int(10e+2),int(10e+3),int(10e+4),int(10e+4)*2,int(10e+4)*5,int(10e+5)*2]

    for pop_size, k_size in zip(pop_sizes, k_sizes):
        pop = xrange(pop_size)
        k = k_size
        t1 = timeit.Timer(stmt='iterSample(pop, %i)'%(k_size), setup='from __main__ import iterSample,pop')
        t2 = timeit.Timer(stmt='sample_from_iterable(pop, %i)'%(k_size), setup='from __main__ import sample_from_iterable,pop')
        t3 = timeit.Timer(stmt='iter_sample_fast(pop, %i)'%(k_size), setup='from __main__ import iter_sample_fast,pop')

        print 'Sampling', k, 'from', pop_size
        print 'Using iterSample', '%1.4f s'%(t1.timeit(number=100) / 100.0)
        print 'Using sample_from_iterable', '%1.4f s'%(t2.timeit(number=100) / 100.0)
        print 'Using iter_sample_fast', '%1.4f s'%(t3.timeit(number=100) / 100.0)
        print ''
```

I also ran a test to check that all the methods indeed do take an unbiased sample of the generator. So for all methods I sampled `1000` elements from `10000` `100000` times and computed the average frequency of occurrence of each item in the population which turns out to be `~.1` as one would expect for all three methods.

Comment: Have you tried `random.sample(list(gen), 20)` -- it might not be too slow!

Comment: What exactly are you sampling from the corpus? Is there any way to represent it as something else than a generator?

Comment: @larsmans words and sentences - I am trying to keep the memory consumption down with using the generator object.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While the answer of Martijn Pieters is correct, it does slow down when `samplesize` becomes large, because using `list.insert` in a loop may have quadratic complexity.

Here's an alternative that, in my opinion, preserves the uniformity while increasing performance:

```
def iter_sample_fast(iterable, samplesize):
    results = []
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    # Fill in the first samplesize elements:
    try:
        for _ in xrange(samplesize):
            results.append(iterator.next())
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("Sample larger than population.")
    random.shuffle(results)  # Randomize their positions
    for i, v in enumerate(iterator, samplesize):
        r = random.randint(0, i)
        if r < samplesize:
            results[r] = v  # at a decreasing rate, replace random items
    return results
```

The difference slowly starts to show for `samplesize` values above `10000`. Times for calling with `(1000000, 100000)`:

- iterSample: 5.05s
- iter_sample_fast: 2.64s

Comment: would using `results = list(itertools.islice(iterator, samplesize))` produce any further improvement?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was just thinking about that. It would make the code simpler, but if a `ValueError` is desired, then there still has to be a check. (I'd personally handle that outside of this function if I were writing it for a library.)

Comment: @larsmans: Instead of `try:`/`except StopIteration:` it'd be `if len(results) < samplesize:`. If `list(islice())` is faster than repeated `.append()` then that'd be worth it.

Comment: This is reservoir sampling? Right https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

Comment: Does anyone have a proof that this procedure is unbiased?

Answer (score 23):

You can't.

You have two options: read the whole generator into a list, then sample from that list, or use a method that reads the generator one by one and picks the sample from that:

```
import random

def iterSample(iterable, samplesize):
    results = []

    for i, v in enumerate(iterable):
        r = random.randint(0, i)
        if r < samplesize:
            if i < samplesize:
                results.insert(r, v) # add first samplesize items in random order
            else:
                results[r] = v # at a decreasing rate, replace random items

    if len(results) < samplesize:
        raise ValueError("Sample larger than population.")

    return results
```

This method adjusts the chance that the next item is part of the sample based on the number of items in the iterable *so far*. It doesn't need to hold more than `samplesize` items in memory.

The solution isn't mine; it was provided as part of [another answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12134726/4279).

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case, seems like something that should be in the standard lib though.

Comment: @MattiLyra: Feel free to propose it's addition to the stdlib.

Comment: So just to check that I understand the logic of the code. It is a uniform sample from the entire generator, because the items are replaced in the result set if `samplesize` is reached before the end of the generator, allowing the later items a chance to be selected?

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to `append` instead of `insert` items? `insert` takes linear time in the average case.

Comment: @larsmans: No! The insertion is instrumental in ensuring that the sample is uniform.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: in that case, my solution would be better asymptotically (though only in *k*, not in *n*).

Comment: why not initialize the size of `results` to be `samplesize`

Comment: @MattiLyra: We'd still need to randomize the results at that time, and pick those `samplesize` items from the iterator, and check if there were at least `samplesize` items. The code wouldn't be any simpler.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no but it would avoid growing the size of the array dynamically, which can be costly if the array is large.

Comment: @MattiLyra: There is no additional cost for adding items to python lists when they are large. See [Python Time Complexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity); appending is O(1) constant cost.

Comment: @larsmans: I'd love to see a comparison for different sizes of `k` and `n`.

Comment: @ MartijnPieters: I'm years late with this comment, but — Appending to a list is O(1) _amortized_ constant cost, as shown on [the page you linked](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). @MattiLyra is correct that reallocating a big array *does* take linear time, even if Python does guarantee that reallocation happens only (exponentially) infrequently. So a solution that reserved all `samplesize` elements up front would be `O(samplesize)` _faster_ than a solution that performed all `lg(samplesize)` reallocations.

Answer (score 8):

Just for the heck of it, here's a one-liner that samples *k* elements without replacement from the *n* items generated in O(*n* lg *k*) time:

```
from heapq import nlargest

def sample_from_iterable(it, k):
    return (x for _, x in nlargest(k, ((random.random(), x) for x in it)))
```

Comment: so you give a random key to each element in `it` when you pass it to to the heap?

Comment: @MattiLyra: yep. It would be even easier to pass `key=random.random()` to `nlargest`, but I'm afraid that would break the heap invariants. This does suppose that your values are comparable in the case of ties between the random keys.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it does since 2.6. If you were looking at the `heapq.py` source code, then scroll down, as `nlargest` is redefined at the end of the file.

Comment: If you were to use `key` the distribution would not be properly random. For any value in the iterable where `random.random()` produced the exact same float, the *first* of the two values of the iterable would always be chosen (because `nlargest(.., key)` uses `(key(value), [decreasing counter starting at 0], value)` tuples). In your method the *larger* of the two values would be preferred in that case. So in both methods there is an (ever so) slight bias.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: hmm, I guess you're right. However, the bias can be made arbitrarily small by letting `random.random` sample from a larger range, so I think the distribution is asymptotically uniform :)

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to get a random sample from a very large text corpus.

[Your excellent synthesis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12581437/1424877) currently shows victory for `iter_sample_fast(gen, pop)`. However, I tried Katriel's recommendation of `random.sample(list(gen), pop)` — and it's blazingly fast by comparison!

```
def iter_sample_easy(iterable, samplesize):
    return random.sample(list(iterable), samplesize)

Sampling 1000 from 10000
Using iter_sample_fast 0.0192 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.0009 s

Sampling 10000 from 100000
Using iter_sample_fast 0.1807 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.0103 s

Sampling 100000 from 1000000
Using iter_sample_fast 1.8192 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.2268 s

Sampling 200000 from 1000000
Using iter_sample_fast 1.7467 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.3297 s

Sampling 500000 from 1000000
Using iter_sample_easy 0.5628 s

Sampling 2000000 from 5000000
Using iter_sample_easy 2.7147 s
```

---

Now, as your corpus gets *very large*, materializing the whole iterable into a `list` will use prohibitively large amounts of memory. But we can still exploit Python's blazing-fast-ness if we can *chunk up the problem*: basically, we pick a `CHUNKSIZE` that is "reasonably small," do `random.sample` on chunks of that size, and then use `random.sample` again to merge them together. We just have to get the boundary conditions right.

I see how to do it if the length of `list(iterable)` is an exact multiple of `CHUNKSIZE` and not bigger than `samplesize*CHUNKSIZE`:

```
def iter_sample_dist_naive(iterable, samplesize):
    CHUNKSIZE = 10000
    samples = []
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        while True:
            first = next(it)
            chunk = itertools.chain([first], itertools.islice(it, CHUNKSIZE-1))
            samples += iter_sample_easy(chunk, samplesize)
    except StopIteration:
        return random.sample(samples, samplesize)
```

However, the code above produces a non-uniform sampling when `len(list(iterable)) % CHUNKSIZE != 0`, and it runs out of memory as `len(list(iterable)) * samplesize / CHUNKSIZE` becomes "very large." Fixing these bugs is above my pay grade, I'm afraid, but a solution is described in [this blog post](https://ballsandbins.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/distributedparallel-reservoir-sampling/) and sounds quite reasonable to me. (Search terms: "distributed random sampling," "distributed reservoir sampling.")

```
Sampling 1000 from 10000
Using iter_sample_fast 0.0182 s
Using iter_sample_dist_naive 0.0017 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.0009 s

Sampling 10000 from 100000
Using iter_sample_fast 0.1830 s
Using iter_sample_dist_naive 0.0402 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.0103 s

Sampling 100000 from 1000000
Using iter_sample_fast 1.7965 s
Using iter_sample_dist_naive 0.6726 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.2268 s

Sampling 200000 from 1000000
Using iter_sample_fast 1.7467 s
Using iter_sample_dist_naive 0.8209 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.3297 s
```

---

Where we really win is when `samplesize` is very small relative to `len(list(iterable))`.

```
Sampling 20 from 10000
Using iterSample 0.0202 s
Using sample_from_iterable 0.0047 s
Using iter_sample_fast 0.0196 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.0001 s
Using iter_sample_dist_naive 0.0004 s

Sampling 20 from 100000
Using iterSample 0.2004 s
Using sample_from_iterable 0.0522 s
Using iter_sample_fast 0.1903 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.0016 s
Using iter_sample_dist_naive 0.0029 s

Sampling 20 from 1000000
Using iterSample 1.9343 s
Using sample_from_iterable 0.4907 s
Using iter_sample_fast 1.9533 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.0211 s
Using iter_sample_dist_naive 0.0319 s

Sampling 20 from 10000000
Using iterSample 18.6686 s
Using sample_from_iterable 4.8120 s
Using iter_sample_fast 19.3525 s
Using iter_sample_easy 0.3162 s
Using iter_sample_dist_naive 0.3210 s

Sampling 20 from 100000000
Using iter_sample_easy 2.8248 s
Using iter_sample_dist_naive 3.3817 s
```

Answer (score 1):

If the population size *n* is known, here is some memory efficient code that loops over a generator, extracting only the target samples:

```
from random import sample
from itertools import count, compress

targets = set(sample(range(n), k=10))
for selection in compress(pop, map(targets.__contains__, count())):
    print(selection)
```

This outputs the selections in the order they are produced by the population generator.

The technique is to use the standard library *random.sample()* to randomly select the target indices for the selections.  The second like determines whether a given index is among the targets and if so gives the corresponding value from the generator.

For example, given targets of `{6, 2, 4}`:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10   ...  output of count()
F  F  T  F  T  F  T  F  F  F  F    ...  is the count in targets?
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K    ...  output of the population generator
-  -  C  -  E  -  G  -  -  -  -    ...  selections emitted by compress
```

This technique is suitable for looping over a corpus too large to fit in memory (otherwise, you could just use *sample()* directly on the population).

Answer (score 0):

If the number of items in the iterator is known (by elsewhere counting the items), another approach is:

```
def iter_sample(iterable, iterlen, samplesize):
    if iterlen < samplesize:
        raise ValueError("Sample larger than population.")
    indexes = set()
    while len(indexes) < samplesize:
        indexes.add(random.randint(0,iterlen))
    indexesiter = iter(sorted(indexes))
    current = indexesiter.next()
    ret = []
    for i, item in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == current:
            ret.append(item)
            try:
                current = indexesiter.next()
            except StopIteration:
                break
    random.shuffle(ret)
    return ret
```

I find this quicker, especially when sampsize is small in relation to iterlen. When the whole, or near to the whole, sample is asked for however, there are issues.

iter_sample (iterlen=10000, samplesize=100) time: (1, 'ms')
iter_sample_fast (iterlen=10000, samplesize=100) time: (15, 'ms')

iter_sample (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=100) time: (65, 'ms')
iter_sample_fast (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=100) time: (1477, 'ms')

iter_sample (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=1000) time: (64, 'ms')
iter_sample_fast (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=1000) time: (1459, 'ms')

iter_sample (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=10000) time: (86, 'ms')
iter_sample_fast (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=10000) time: (1480, 'ms')

iter_sample (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=100000) time: (388, 'ms')
iter_sample_fast (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=100000) time: (1521, 'ms')

iter_sample (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=1000000) time: (25359, 'ms')
iter_sample_fast (iterlen=1000000, samplesize=1000000) time: (2178, 'ms')

Answer (score 0):

Fastest method until proven otherwise when you have an idea about how long the generator is (and will be asymptotically uniformly distributed):

```
def gen_sample(generator_list, sample_size, iterlen):
    num = 0
    inds = numpy.random.random(iterlen) <= (sample_size * 1.0 / iterlen)
    results = []
    iterator = iter(generator_list)
    gotten = 0
    while gotten < sample_size: 
        try:
            b = iterator.next()
            if inds[num]: 
                results.append(b)
                gotten += 1
            num += 1    
        except: 
            num = 0
            iterator = iter(generator_list)
            inds = numpy.random.random(iterlen) <= ((sample_size - gotten) * 1.0 / iterlen)
    return results
```

It is both the fastest on the small iterable as well as the huge iterable (and probably all in between then)

```
# Huge
res = gen_sample(xrange(5000000), 200000, 5000000)
timing: 1.22s

# Small
z = gen_sample(xrange(10000), 1000, 10000) 
timing: 0.000441
```

Comment: What is the `except` supposed to catch. The end of one iterator?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a radically different variation that uses a set as a bucket of items. It starts by priming the bucket with `pool` items, and then yield samples from the bucket, replacing them from the iterator, finally it drains what is left of the bucket.

`HashWrapper` serves to hide unhashable types from `set`.

```py
class HashWrapper(tuple):
    """Wrap unhashable type."""
    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)


def randomize_iterator(data: Iterator, pool=100) -> Iterator:
    """
    Randomize an iterator.
    """

    bucket = set()
    iterator = iter(data)

    # Prime the bucket
    for _ in range(pool):
        try:
            bucket.add(HashWrapper(next(iterator)))
        except StopIteration:
            # We've drained the iterator
            break

    # Start picking from the bucket and replacing new items from the iterator
    for item in iterator:
        sample, = random.sample(bucket, 1)
        yield sample
        bucket.remove(sample)
        bucket.add(HashWrapper(item))

    # Drain the bucket
    yield from random.sample(bucket, len(bucket))
```