# Go to a specific line and read the next few in Python

Tags: python, file, memory, line, fastq

I have this huge (61GB) [FASTQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) file of which I want to create a random subset, but which I cannot load into memory. The problem with FASTQs is that every four lines belong together, otherwise I would just create a list of random integers and only write the lines at these integers to my subset file.

So far, I have this:

```
import random
num = []    
while len(num) < 50000000:
    ran = random.randint(0,27000000)
    if (ran%4 == 0) and (ran not in num):
        num.append(ran)
num = sorted(num)

fastq = open("all.fastq", "r", 4)
subset = open("sub.fastq", "w")
for i,line in enumerate(fastq):
    for ran in num:
        if ran == i:
            subset.append(line)
```

I have no idea how to reach the next three lines in the file before going to the next random integer. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can replace the first half of your code with `random.sample`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import random
num = sorted([random.randint(0,27000000/4)*4 for i in range(50000000/4)])

lines_to_write = 0
with open("all.fastq", "r") as fastq:
    with open("sub.fastq", "w") as subset:
        for i,line in enumerate(fastq):
            if len(num)==0:
                break
            if i == num[0]:
                num.pop(0)
                lines_to_write = 4
            if lines_to_write>0:
                lines_to_write -= 1
                subset.write(line)
```

Comment: You need to check if `num` is empty. Also, `i = num[0]` should be `i == num[0]`

Comment: Won't that stop and throw an error once num is empty but the file has still more lines to iterate over?

Ah, I didn't see @LevLevitsky already mentioned that.

Comment: You both are right. I did this code without trying, and am glad you reviewed it. Now it should (hopefully) work.

Comment: It does for my small test files. :-)

Comment: Great! Btw: How long does it run on a 61 GB file?

Comment: I guess about an hour :) Depending on the storage drive, of course.

Comment: Yes, I would estimate that, too.

Comment: Only, it takes a lot longer than that... Oh well, at least it seems to work.

Comment: MAybe you could use a `mmap` to speed things up. Then, use `for i, line in enumerate(iter(mm.readline, "")):`, with `mm` being the mmap. In my experience, this might lead to 10-30% speed boost.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Iterate over the file in chunks of four lines.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)
2. [Take a random sample from that iterator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581437/python-random-sample-with-a-generator)

The idea is that you can sample from a generator without random access, by iterating through it and choosing (or not) each element in turn.

Comment: The example you linked for iterating over the file doesn't seem to work with files.

Comment: @Lilith-Elina the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/434411/398968) works fine for me. What problem do you get?

Comment: Ah, for that answer, I have the problem that izip_longest neither works on my PC nor on our Linux server.

Comment: Have you imported it from itertools? `from itertools import izip_longest` Alternatively just `import itertools` and then `itertools.izip_longest(...)`