# Selecting random rows with python and writing to a new file

Tags: python, random

I need to open a csv file, select 1000 random rows and save those rows to a new file. I'm stuck and can't see how to do it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So there are two parts to this problem. Firstly getting every row of your csv, secondly randomly sampling. I would suggest constructing your list of rows with a list comprehension. Something along the lines of:

```
with open("your_file.csv", "rb") as source:
    lines = [line for line in source]
```

Once you've got that you want to take a random sample of those lines. Luckily python has a function that does just that.

```
import random
random_choice = random.sample(lines, 1000)
```

Once you've got those lines you want to write them back to a new file (though I assume you already know how given that a quick google reveals this), so I will include an example just for completeness's sake:

```
with open("new_file.csv", "wb") as sink:
    sink.write("\n".join(random_choice))
```

which just outputs your choice as a newline delimited string to the file of your choice. It's also worth noting that in this case it doesn't really matter that you're dealing with a csv, just another file with some lines.

If you're working with a very large file or concerned about taking up too much memory you should replace the above list comprehension with a generator and then sample from that instead, but that process isn't nearly as straightforward. If you want advice on making that more performant you should look at this question: [Python random sample with a generator iterable iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581437/python-random-sample-with-a-generator)

Comment: I tried this and got the following error message.                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 41, in <module>
    import random
  File "/auto/data/nhine/Python/random.py", line 42, in <module>
    random_choice = random.sample(lines, 1000)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sample'

Comment: You've got a namespace error. Don't name your file random.py

Comment: I have now got the code to run ( I had called my file random.py and that was causing problems), but it doesn't seem to be producing an output file.

Answer (score -1):

The basic procedure is this:

**1. Open the input file**

This can be accomplished with the basic builtin `open` function.

**2.  Open the output file**

You'll probably use the same method that you chose in step #1, but you'll need to open the file in write mode.

**3. Read the input file to a variable**

It's often preferable to read the file one line at a time, and operate on that one line before reading the next, but if memory is not a concern, you can also read the entire thing into a variable all at once.

**4.  Choose selected lines**

There will be any number of ways to do this, depending on how you did step #3, and your requirements.  You could use `filter`, or a list comprehension, or a `for` loop with an `if` statement, etc.  The best way depends on the particular constraints of your goal.

**5.  Write the selected lines**

Take the selected lines you've chosen in step #4 and write them to the file.

**6.  Close the files**

It's generally good practice to close the files you've opened to prevent resource leaks.

Comment: The csv module does not open files, nor is it complicated. Also in python you should never have to explicitly close a file since the `with` syntax is so powerful. Also OP is looking for randomly selected lines, not a filter.

Comment: After looking at the docs, you're right about csv not opening files directly - haven't used it myself.  I guess "complicated" is pretty subjective, but sure.  As for `with`, it internally closes the file.  If the OP decides to use `with`, he'll be doing that anyways.  And as for the random part, I interpreted "random" in a colloquial sense.  If he really meant he's going to sample them using a pseudorandom generator, then I misunderstood.

Comment: Using a filter to randomly sample is extremely inefficient, unintuitive, and generally difficult to read if you can even get it working. There's a difference between a module internally closing a file and directly calling the close method, and a confusion between the two can lead to all kinds of silly errors (like IOErrors closing already closed files.) I think this answer would be great for another question, but it doesn't seem to take the OP's question, or python into account.