# random.sample on Django querysets: How will sampling on querysets affect performance?

Tags: python, django

I was trying to sample a few records from my queryset for performance like:

```
from random import sample
from my_app import MyModel


my_models = MyModel.objects.all()

# sample only a few of records for performance
my_models_sample = sample(my_models, 5)

for model in my_models_sample:
    model.some_expensive_calculation
```

But I felt like it made only worse in terms of execution time.

How does `random.sample()` actually works behind the scene? And will it be rather performance burden on django querysets?

Comment: your query returns a list of all objects from the database already. sample makes a random selection of 5 (unique) among them - without connecting to the database. this is a cheap operation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `random.sample()` will force evaluate queryset `my_models`, the execution time of your program will heavily depend on the total number of `MyModel` objects in your database.

To improve performance and avoid loading entire query set into memory, you may end up implementing your own sampling function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581437/python-random-sample-with-a-generator) together with [`.iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) method.

Alternatively, you can also rely on database server to do the sampling for you via [`order_by('?')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) as follows:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('?')[:5]
```

Personally, I wouldn't recommend the latter one as queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you’re using. *(especially for MySQL)*

Answer (score 4):

Why not let the database do the shuffling and limiting and compare the times?

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('?')[:5]
```

Although [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) states that this may be expensive, in your case as you are fetching all the rows anyway, I suspect there will be a difference. The magnitude of the difference will depend on how big the data set is (and of course, your database backend).

Answer (score 3):

You are using `random.sample()` on a QuerySet object.

If you actually want to get 5 random samples as QuerySet then you can rather use this

```
random_objects = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('?')[:5]
```

This will get you 5 random objects and reduce your time of sampling.

PS: I will also check why is it taking so long that `random.sample()` is taking so much time for that operation, if ofcourse I find something. :)

Comment: @ozgur : I have edited the answer. I was using Mongo and hence it worked for me.. wasn't wrong according to my setup :D

Comment: also you can omit `all()`