# Python Get Random Unique N Pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, math, graph, combinations

Say I have a `range(1, n + 1)`. I want to get `m` unique pairs.

What I found is, if the number of pairs is close to `n(n-1)/2` (maxiumum number of pairs), one can't simply generate random pairs everytime because they will start overriding eachother. I'm looking for a somewhat lazy solution, that will be very efficient (in Python's world).

My attempt so far:

```
def get_input(n, m):

    res = str(n) + "\n" + str(m) + "\n"
    buffet = range(1, n + 1)
    points = set()

    while len(points) < m:
        x, y = random.sample(buffet, 2)
        points.add((x, y)) if x > y else points.add((y, x)) # meeh

    for (x, y) in points:
        res += "%d %d\n" % (x, y);

    return res
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach which works by taking a number in the range `0 to n*(n-1)/2 - 1` and decodes it to a unique pair of items in the range `0 to n-1`. I used 0-based math for convenience, but you could of course add 1 to all of the returned pairs if you want:

```
import math
import random

def decode(i):
    k = math.floor((1+math.sqrt(1+8*i))/2)
    return k,i-k*(k-1)//2

def rand_pair(n):
    return decode(random.randrange(n*(n-1)//2))

def rand_pairs(n,m):
    return [decode(i) for i in random.sample(range(n*(n-1)//2),m)]
```

For example:

```
>>> >>> rand_pairs(5,8)
[(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 1), (1, 0), (4, 0)]
```

The math is hard to easily explain, but the `k` in the definition of `decode` is obtained by solving a quadratic equation which gives the number of [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) which are `<= i`, and where `i` falls in the sequence of triangular numbers tells you how to decode a unique pair from it. The interesting thing about this decode is that it doesn't use `n` at all but implements a one-to-one correspondence from the set of natural numbers (starting at 0) to the set of all pairs of natural numbers.

Comment: Is there a link to a more comprehensive explanation? Thanks.

Comment: This is perfect by the way.

Comment: @AfonsoMatos I don't know of a link. I started with the enumeration `(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)` (which is the sort of enumeration you need if it isn't to depend on `n`) noticed that there was 1 which started with 1, 2 which started with 2, etc. To get the pair from `i`, I needed to know what "block" `i` is in. `i = 7`, for example is in the 4-block *because* `1+2+3 <= 7 < 1+2+3+4` which translates to `3(3-1)/2 <= 7 < 4(4-1)/2` If you solve `7 = k(k-1)/2` and turn to an integer, you get the `k`. A little more algebra gets you the other index.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `combinations` to generate all pairs and use `sample` to choose randomly.  Admittedly only lazy in the "not much to type" sense, and not in the use a generator not a list sense :-)

```
from itertools import combinations
from random import sample

n = 100
sample(list(combinations(range(1,n),2)),5)
```

If you want to improve performance you can make it lazy by studying this 
[Python random sample with a generator / iterable / iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581437/python-random-sample-with-a-generator-iterable-iterator)

the generator you want to sample from is this: `combinations(range(1,n)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any thing on your line can improve. After all, as your `m` get closer and closer to the limit `n(n-1)/2`, you have thinner and thinner chance to find the unseen pair.

I would suggest to split into two cases: if `m` is small, use your random approach. But if `m` is large enough, try

```
 pairs = list(itertools.combination(buffet,2))
 ponits = random.sample(pairs, m)
```

Now you have to determine the threshold of `m` that determines which code path it should go. You need some math here to find the right trade off.