# SQL statement to randomly select one row having a certain criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming that we have the following MySQL table:

```
ID | Name | Last_Name | Location  |
1  | Alex | Griff     | DT        |
2  | John | Doe       | York      |
3  | Pat  | Benat     | DT        |
4  | Jack | Darny     | DT        |
5  | Duff | Hill      | York      |
```

I want to create an sql statement that selects randomly one row of each location and store them in a new table.

For example:

```
2  | John | Doe       | York      |
3  | Pat  | Benat     | DT        |
```

OR

```
4  | Jack | Darny     | DT        |
5  | Duff | Hill      | York      |
```

I would like to execute this on SQL since it's much faster than doing it on a Java program and using `HashMap<K,V>` and then storing the values again in another table.

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249301/simple-random-samples-from-a-sql-database

Comment: @TomRon . . . The questions are quite different, because this question is about a random sample from each location, rather than an overall random sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://push-hard.blogspot.com/2009/11/mysql-select-random-row-from-each-group.html) has the solution. I simply modified the query to your table definition, as follows:

```
SELECT tmp.ID, tmp.Name, tmp.Last_Name, tmp.Location
FROM profiles
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY RAND()) tmp ON (profiles.Location = tmp.Location)
GROUP BY tmp.Location
ORDER BY profiles.Location;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/227bde/10)</kbd>

Comment: This request assumes that the values for `tmp` all come from the same record.  In fact, the MySQL documentation *specifically* warns against this use of group by:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random sample for each location, you have several options.  I think the easiest is a variable approach that will work well if your table is not super big.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             @rn := if(@location = location, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
             @location := location
      from table t cross join
           (select @location := '', @rn := 0) vars
      order by location, rand()
     ) t
where rn = 1;
```

This assigns a sequential number to the locations and then chooses the first one.

Comment: is this mysql? it seems complicated.

Comment: @user3620037 . . . (1) It doesn't seem complicated to me.  (2) You have a somewhat complicated request.