# Taking a proportion of a dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe with ~50,000 rows and I want to randomly select a proportion of rows from that dataframe based on a number of conditions. Specifically, I have a column called 'type of use' and, for each field in that column, I want to select a different proportion of rows.

For instance:

```
df[df['type of use'] == 'housing'].sample(frac=0.2)
```

This code returns 20% of all the rows which have 'housing' as their 'type of use'. The problem is I do not know how to do this for the remaining fields in a way that is 'idiomatic'. I also do not know how I could take the result from this sampling to form a new dataframe.

Comment: you need to iterate over all unique filter options and store in a dictionary of dataframes, check answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a unique list for all the values in the column by `list(df['type of use'].unique())` and iterate like below:

```
for i in list(df['type of use'].unique()):
    print(df[df['type of use'] == i].sample(frac=0.2))
```

or

```
i = 0 
while i < len(list(df['type of use'].unique())):
    df1 = df[(df['type of use']==list(df['type of use'].unique())[i])].sample(frac=0.2)
    print(df1.head())
    i = i + 1
```

For storing you can create a dictionary:

```
dfs = ['df' + str(x) for x in list(df2['type of use'].unique())]
dicdf = dict()
i = 0 
while i < len(dfs):
    dicdf[dfs[i]] = df[(df['type of use']==list(df2['type of use'].unique())[i])].sample(frac=0.2)
    i = i + 1
print(dicdf)
```

This will print a dictionary of the dataframes.
You can print what you like to see for example for housing sample : `print (dicdf['dfhousing'])`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @anky_91. This is generally what I was trying to achieve. I am thinking about 'replicating' my code in SQL for something else - do you know if there is an SQL equivalent to df[df['type of use'] == i].sample(frac=0.2), for example?

Comment: May be this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249301/simple-random-samples-from-a-sql-database??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is coming in 2+ years late, but I think you can do this without iterating, based on help I received to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69596464/for-each-unique-value-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-how-can-i-randomly-select-a/69627924?noredirect=1#comment123098242_69627924).   Applying it to your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
percentage_to_flag = 0.2 #I'm assuming you want the same %age for all 'types of use'?

#First, create a new 'helper' dataframe:
random_state = 41  # Change to get different random values.
df_sample = df.groupby("type of use").apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=(math.ceil(percentage_to_flag * len(x))),random_state=random_state))
df_sample = df_sample.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)  #may need this to simplify multi-index dataframe

# Now, mark the random sample in a new column in the original dataframe:
df["marked"] = False
df.loc[df_sample.index, "marked"] = True
```