# How to randomly subsample on a set of unique documents from a sql database?

Tags: sql

I have a sql table like below

[image]

So the `id` column contains the unique elements `a`, `b`, and `c`. I would like to choose at random  (uniformly) 2 out of `a`, `b`, and `c` and then take all rows whose `id` is either one of these 2 elements. For example, if `a` and `b` are chosen. Then my desired result is

[image]

- I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249301/simple-random-samples-from-a-sql-database) thread, but it is about subsample uniformly on the set of all rows. On the other hand, my subsample is extracted from the set of unique elements of a column `id` and then take all rows whose `id` belongs to this subsample.
- My work is on Sagemaker of AWS, so I can extract the whole dataframe and perform subsample and extraction by Python. However, I guess this is slower than performing subsample directly by sql.

Could you elaborate on how to efficiently subsample in this case?

Comment: It does not make any sense to have duplicate IDs. Let's say the random function returns `ID='a'`, which row am I supposed to display?

Comment: @Christophe `id` is just a name of a column. The random function can return the row number to identify the chosen row.

Comment: OK, just in case I prefer warning ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in MS SQL Server you can use next trick:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id in (
    -- select 2 random id
    SELECT top 2 id FROM t GROUP by id ORDER BY NEWID()
);
```

[MSSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/cdf63206e65c53b574ffe237b6b0eae8/)

I mean this query can be easy adopted to other RDBMS versions

Comment: Could you explain what is the purpose of `MIN(id)`?

Comment: `MIN` in this case can be changed to `MAX` it only served to get single value within group

Comment: I'm confused. Because we `GROUP by id`, each group has exactly 1 id. Is it redundant to use `MIN(id)`?

Comment: The inner query needs for return 2 random `id`, i can not use `distinct` with order by `newid()`, so i used `group by` and some aggregation for get distinct ids. May be you have another way to do this, i'll gad to know how :)

Comment: I meant if I remove `MIN(id)` from your code, it still works fine and returns 2 distinct random id's :) Please see [here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/b434ba638959853408f8776e3157e347/).

Comment: Nice. Just updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```sql
SELECT rownum, id, col1
FROM (SELECT  row_number() OVER () rownum, id, col1
    FROM my_table 
    ORDER BY id) b
 WHERE rownum = round(random() * 4) + 1;
```

[dbFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2ux3wbkia6pG1hdxRUwupQ/1)
`random()` returns a value between 0 and 1 so you need to multiply to a factor that gives a large enough range. Round it and ad 1 to have an integer and 1 as lowest value.